# Multiple admins in Django is it possible

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to add multiple admins in Django's admin panel and how I will register them(they need to have the same rights)? And also is it possible to add another 2 roles to the panel with different rights?
I read a lot about it and can't find the answer.

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: Visit the Django admin (localhost:/admin) and explore the Users page/tab. When creating or editing a user you'll find options to make him/her a staff or superuser(admin), etc. You'll also find lists of permission you can assign to a user there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create/modify a user and while creating a user you can select their role if they are admin, staff, etc. You can also customize user's permissions when you create their account or if the accounts are already created you can modify it.
To avoid having to assign permission's again and again, i would suggest you create a new group and add the permission that the user in that group should have and then assign the desired user in that group.